# Sql query a word inside field

Tags: sql

I have a database field called willingness populated with text like:

```
shopping,pool,pc,games
shopping,pool,pc,games
swimming, pool, pc, games
```

I need sql query that queries the fileds which have "shopping" inside?

TY

Comment: what was the reason to store the data in such unusable form?

Comment: Its data from rss field, wasn't made by me

Comment: So then split it up when you parse the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should be enough:

```
select *
from table
where willingness like '%shopping%'
```

this will work in sql server

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator for this purpose. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE willingness LIKE '%shopping%'
```

However, if the field is simply storing a comma-separated list of tags, you might want to change the schema instead - as it stands, the schema is not normalized. For example, the table could have  `UserId` and  `WillingnessTagId` columns with the appropriate foreign-keys.

Answer (score 1):

Select * from table1 where willingness like '%shopping%'

Answer (score 1):

Very inefficient, as this really should be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), but should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE willingness LIKE '%shopping%'
```

In a normalized database, you would have a willingness table with an ID for each (say 1 for shopping) and a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to this lookup table. The query then would be much more efficient:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE willingness_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why we normalize.

```
AND (willingness = 'shopping'
OR willingness like 'shopping,%'
OR willingness like '%,shopping'
OR willingness like '%,shopping,%'
OR willingness like '%, shopping'
OR willingness like '%, shopping,%')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the JOB :

```
select willingness from table where willingness LIKE '%shopping%'
```

I recommands you to read about string comparison in MYSQL statement : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/string-comparison-functions.html

I assume you are using MySQL, if not please tell us what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT store the data in your database like this. Let me explain:

You can use the solution which people mention here (`like %shopping%` etc), but you're literally **asking for trouble** this way.

Read about normalization. Instead of a `willingness` field, you could have a `willingness` table which would look somehow like this:

```
person_id     willing

1             pool
2             shopping
2             pool
3             swimming
3             games
```

Etc.

Then you only need a query like `select distinct person_id from willingness where willing = "pool"`. That's it - much safer and probably faster.